# Simple Errors in Flash CS6 - ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

This is probably super simple. I have created a basic replay button in Flash CS6 Pro, ActionScript 3.0. The instance name is correct, but I get a syntax error and '{'expected. What an I doing wrong?

Code:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

playAgain_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, f_playAgain);

function f_playAgain (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

EDIT:

The errors are as follows:

Scene=Scene 1, layer=actions, frame=1161, Line 1 Syntax Error.

Scene=Scene 1, layer=actions, frame=1161, Line 7 '{' expected.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that removing the space in here:

```
f_playAgain (event:MouseEvent):void
```

might do the job

```
f_playAgain(event:MouseEvent):void
```